# Composite primary key including Identity increment SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql, relational-database

I wonder if there is a way to create a composite PK of 2 fields, where one is `uniqueidentifier` and another - `int` that should autoincrement. Example PK is `ID, No`:

```
ID         No     Date
6D...41    1      2014-01-01
6D...41    2      2014-01-02
6D...41    3      2014-01-03

3R...D8    1      2014-01-03
3R...D8    2      2014-01-03
3R...D8    3      2014-01-05
3R...D8    4      2014-01-09

6D...41    4      2014-01-10
```

The `No` column should increment within one `ID` only. Also, is it possible if some record gets deleted, the `No` column should change like:

Before:

```
ID         No     Date
6D...41    1      2014-01-01
6D...41    2      2014-01-02  delete this
6D...41    3      2014-01-03
```

After:

```
ID         No     Date
6D...41    1      2014-01-01
6D...41    2      2014-01-03
```

So, when one record is deleted, the increment should change respectively for all records by sorting `Date` column. I'm not asking for the whole solution, of course, just an advice, suggestions or alternatives. Will it be better to handle all changes on the table in database (with triggers, etc.) or in program logic?

Thanks a lot

Comment: @MitchWheat, I first tried to create a composite PK, one that is uniqueidentifier, and another - integer with Identity = 'on'. But it does not give me desired result. Identity increment does not work within the first PK, it increments based on the previous record.

Comment: I know I can achieve it programmatically, i mean track each change of table and assign appropriate IDs. I'm just looking for a better solution.

Comment: I think I would do it with a view and just generate NO series.  The ID is not a uniqueidentifier.